# Asynchronous Programming with OOP in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, asynchronous, design-patterns

I am having a problem writing clean OOP code, say in TypeScript, while some of my objects contain async methods: what 'ends up' happening is that I am writing static methods, and whichever object or method 'uses' these static methods is 'contaminated' and needs to be converted into a sort of promise itself... I am sure I doing something wrong - is there some architecture trick that I am missing?

Let's take a concrete example: I am writing a Node JS app with a model object of my MongoDB document. Nothing fancy. However, when I use the object's methods in my app, doesn't matter in which class, every method that uses the methods has to be async. And then every method that uses the method that uses the method has to be async as well... etc.

Is there a way to use the MongoDB async operations in such a way as to at least keep up the façade of normal OOP architecture, or is there an entirely new sort of logic I need to learn to write async OOP apps?

Hope I made my question clear,

Comment: Why do you think that async methods are not "normal OOP architecture"?

Comment: Because - and I am sure I am wrong, hence the question - it seems like there is a sot of callback hell inside the app when I write even one async method (the object that depends on that function, and all the objects that depend on the object that depends on that function etc...)

Comment: The whole point of introducing the `async` and `await` keywords into JS was to let you write async code in a normal way, without all the callback stuff.

Comment: @EliRotenberg you just described JavaScript in a nutshell. If one thing is async then everything starts to be.

Comment: In some other runtimes there are ways to explicitly block the reactor/executor when doing an async call, thus preventing async from propagating further and negating some of its benefits. Not sure if javascript can do this, though.

Comment: @MattTimmermans right, but if I want to use these async static methods in a method of some other class, I need to use the await keyword, and to use the await keyword, this function needs to become async as well, and then the methods that depend on this method need to become async... right up to the main scope. That seems like bad design.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I fear that you are right, but then again, perhaps there are better practices that I am missing here.

Comment: @EliRotenberg async methods do not have to be static.  But yes, they are contagious. That's known as the red/blue function problem: https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/  It's not ideal, but it's the best that can be done without requiring some very special capabilities from the language/system used to implement JS.

Comment: @MattTimmermans can you 'answer' this so I can pick this comment as the answer? Precisely the reference/def I was looking for.

Comment: Can you create an example of your class system? It kind of sounds like it could be done better.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski probably :-) however the specific issue I was referring to is the one Matt linked to. Thank you for the willingness to help.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no, JS cannot do that. You can approach it from the opposite direction by composing and lifting all the functions that need to run after the async task. So, each function works with synchronous data, however, it's lifted to async context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async methods don't have to be static, and there really isn't any reason that a program using async operations can't have the same overall structure as one that doesn't.

Async operations are contagious, however.  That's known as the red/blue function problem: https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

It's not ideal, but it's the best that can be done without requiring some very special capabilities from the language/system used to implement JS.  You can either have threads, which come with their own problems, or you can have some mechanism for copying call stacks around, like Go and upcoming Java project Loom.